# how to open running yum command if the terminal is closed mistakenly

Tags: linux, process, yum

I ran the command yum install  without -y parameter, and after I hit enter the terminal is closed mistakenly and now the yum is lock and I cannot do any further operation.

While searching I came across that if I want to bring that process to foreground we need to hit command

```
fg %<job_id>
```

But I am not sure how to get the job ID and also I am not sure will this work.

Comment: Is yum even running ? You can `ps aux | grep yum` or `sudo killall yum` , then remove the lock https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2009-May/msg00663.html and use yum history to re-run the transaction.

Comment: @Panther Yes the process is still running and I know this will work but I want to learn how can I bring back my running yum command if that is still incomplete, or we cannot do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't bring it back anymore.

`fg` is for putting back in foreground a job that was started in background (with `&`) or interrupted (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) on the *current* shell.

If you closed that window, there's not really a way to get it back, since the shell process is gone.

You can use something like `tmux` or `screen` to allow you to reattach to a session, but in that case you need to start them before you start using the terminal, so it wouldn't help you in your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

If yum is somehow still running despite the shell and terminal window being gone (which is unlikely), you'd have to use a program like `reptyr` to re-attach to it, unless you started it in a `screen` or `tmux` session in the first place. To do so, find the PID, then run `reptyr PID`.